# How do I set the bounds to the city?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I have the city name i.e. Austin, TX. I need to use that city as the bounds parameter when searching for establishments. Any idea how to do that?

```
        let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
        filter.type = .establishment
        placesClient.autocompleteQuery(textField.text!, bounds: nil, filter: filter, callback: {(results, error) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                print("Autocomplete error \(error)")
                return
            }

            if let results = results {
                print(results)
            }
        })
```

Comment: Do you need like that: if user searches in search bar for any place/location/etc. so user will get all the results from particular city/region?

Comment: So in my past controller, I collect the city name. In this view controller they type in a place and it should predict places in the city they entered. You can assume that there is already a var name city and is populated with a city.

Answer (score 1):

I did not work with GMSAutocompleteFilter but I have implemented with google api, so here I am sharing some sample code, try this:

Take search bar & implement its delegate & call google places api as follows. Here, you need to pass the city name. So after calling this api you will get the results. With this results, I am storing place name in two different strings i.e. strMainTitle & strSubTitle. And finally reload the table to display list. Also you have to implement tableview delegate & datasource methods to display list on table.(Here you need to take tableview to display search text query).

```
    // MARK:- SearchBar Delegate methods
    func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar,textDidChange searchText: String)
    {
        let strCityString = "your city name"
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let apiServerKey = "Put here your apiServerkey"
        var urlString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=\(apiServerKey)&input=\(strCityString)"+"\(searchBarObj.text!)"
        urlString = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        session.dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: urlString)!) {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
            do {

                if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:[]) as? [String:AnyObject] {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    let returnedPlaces: NSArray? = json["predictions"] as? NSArray//                    print("Predictions Retrunedplaces: \(returnedPlaces)")
                    self.arraySearchResults.removeAllObjects()
                    self.arraySearchResults.addObjectsFromArray(json["predictions"] as! [AnyObject])// (returnedPlaces!)
                    self.strMainTitle.removeAllObjects()
                    self.strSubTitle.removeAllObjects()
                    for index in 0..<returnedPlaces!.count {

                        if let returnedPlace = returnedPlaces?[index] as? NSDictionary {
                            var placeName = ""

                            if let name = returnedPlace["description"] as? NSString {
                                placeName = name as String
                            }

                            var fullNameArr = placeName.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
                            var strname = String()
                            let laststring:Int = fullNameArr.count - 1
                            for i in 1..<fullNameArr.count
                            {
                                if i == laststring //fullNameArr.count - 1
                                {
                                    strname += "\(fullNameArr[i])"
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    strname += "\(fullNameArr[i])"+","
                                }

                            }
                                    self.strMainTitle.addObject(placeName.componentsSeparatedByString(",").first!)
                            self.strSubTitle.addObject(strname)
                        }
                    }
                        self.tableviewForSearchBar.reloadData()
                    })

                }
            } catch {

            }

            }.resume()
    }
```